# Codeigniter - variables with tags like {title}

Tags: php, codeigniter, templates

Im building a website with Codeigniter, and in my views I dont liek putting variables like:

```
<?=$title?>
```

I would much rather to write in HTML

```
{title}
```

And to replace it somehow.

How can I do that?

Comment: I know different templating engines use different syntax to insert PHP into HTML, but I'm not familiar with which one Codeigniter uses. I know Laravel uses `Blade` syntax, which is `{{ $variable }}`, so maybe looking into a different engine/framework is the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CodeIgniter has a template parser to do exactly what you are wanting.

Here are some examples from their doc:

```
$this->load->library('parser');

$data = array(
            'blog_title' => 'My Blog Title',
            'blog_heading' => 'My Blog Heading'
            );

$this->parser->parse('blog_template', $data);
```

And here is the HTML

```
<html>
<head>
<title>{blog_title}</title>
</head>
<body>

<h3>{blog_heading}</h3>

{blog_entries}
<h5>{title}</h5>
<p>{body}</p>
{/blog_entries}
</body>
</html>
```

The full documentation for it can be found on their site [here](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/parser.html)

Answer (score 0):

Load up the [Template Parser Class](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/parser.html).